# When does html audio/video control start receiving file content from the server to the browser

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio

I have html audio/video control on my web page, like below code.

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="somefolder/audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> 
</audio>

<video width="350" height="250" controls>
  <source src="somefolder/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

When does the control start receiving audio/video file content from the server? Is it when I click on play button or it start receiving when I visit the page first time.

Answer (score 0):

Audio and video tag load source when you visit page fisrt time. However, it's possible to lazy-load video, it will load only image and video will start loading when play button will be clicked. You can set it with attribute `preload="metadata"` in audio/video tag, e.g. if you have tag `<video width="350" height="250" controls><source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>`, just add attribute `<video preload="metadata" width="350" height="250" controls><source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>` and your video will start loading on play button click.